# My Form built in HTML5 and PHP is returning a white space

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having issues with my form built is HTML and PHP. It is returning a white page after I clicked to submit. The website is online already http://diegodiasp.com/

The html is the following:

```html
<form class="bg-light p-4 p-md-5 contact-form" action="./contactform.php" method="POST" >
       <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Your Name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="mail"  placeholder="Your Email">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message"  cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
       </div>
      </form>
```

And the PHP is as bellow:

```html
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){


    $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);   
    $email = addslashes($_POST['mail']);   
    $message = addslashes($_POST['message']);  

    $to = "info@diegodiasp.com";
    $subject = "Contact - Diego Dias Front End";
        $body = "Name: ".$name."\r\n".
        "Email: ".$email."\r\n".
        "Message: ".$message;
    $header = "From:info@diegodiasp.com"."\r\n"."Reply-To:".$email."\r\n"."X=Mailer:PHP/".phpversion();

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header)){
        echo("Email succesfully sent!");

    }else{
        echo("Email not sent!");

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: A common cause for a blank page is an unrecoverable (fatal) PHP error occurring. On a production environment, you'll have to check your webserver's logs to see what error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox for the email address is called mail.
You are checking if 'email' isset and not 'mail'.

Correct your php to the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['mail']) && !empty($_POST['mail'])){
```